# How to make openssl verify the MAC of a downloaded file?

Tags: linux, openssl, cryptography

I often use `openssl` to compute MACs of downloaded files:

```
openssl sha1 file.tar.xz 
SHA1(file.tar.xz)= 6fb6198e83876c93e7e70a48363887dc1f6744ed
```

I want to provide the original MAC (from the download page) to openssl as an extra option, so that I don't have to do an extra string comparison manually.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sha1sum instead. Along with file.tar.xz you'll should have a file named  file.tar.xz.sha1 with the following contents: `6fb6198e83876c93e7e70a48363887dc1f6744ed file.tar.xz`

To verify the checksum run the following command: `sha1sum -c file.tar.xz.sha1`

A good results with look like this:

```
sha1sum -c file.tar.xz.sha1
file.tar.xz: OK
```

A bad result will look like this:

```
sha1sum -c file.tar.xz.sha1
file.tar.xz: FAILED
sha1sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
```

This will compare the checksum in file.tar.xz.tar with the calculated checksum from file.tar.xz.

Similar utilities exists for different hashes:

- sha1sum
- sha224sum
- sha256sum
- sha384sum
- sha512sum
- md5sum

Comment: Thank you. However, openssl groups all of these separate programs into one, which is a nice feature of it.

Comment: openssl does not have the option to feed the the expected hash. If you want to use openssl you can use the follwing:
`[ "\`openssl sha1 file.tar.xz | cut -d' ' -f2\`" = "6fb6198e83876c93e7e70a48363887dc1f6744ed" ] && echo "GOOD" || echo "BAD"`